# JQuery imgAreaSelect setting aspectRatio with PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery

I'm sure this is something simple but I'm a total numpty when it comes to Java Script. I've written (or copied and adapted I should say...) an image resize script using the Jquery plugin imgAreaSelect & Ajax. It works as it should. I only have one single issue with it: I want to be able to set the aspect ratio dynamically.

Here's the code of the script:

```
function getSizes(im,obj)
{
    var x_axis = obj.x1;
    var x2_axis = obj.x2;
    var y_axis = obj.y1;
    var y2_axis = obj.y2;
    var thumb_width = obj.width;
    var thumb_height = obj.height;
    if(thumb_width > 0)
        {
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"GET",
                        url:"imagecrop/ajax_image.php?t=ajax&img="+$("#image_name").val()+"&w="+thumb_width+"&h="+thumb_height+"&x1="+x_axis+"&y1="+y_axis,
                        cache:false,
                        success:function(rsponse)
                            {
                             $("#cropimage").hide();
                                $("#thumbs").html("");
                                $("#thumbs").html("<img src='uploads/"+rsponse+"' />");
                            }
                    });
        }
    else
        alert("Please select portion..!");
    }
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img#photo').imgAreaSelect({
        aspectRatio: '225:300',
        onSelectEnd: getSizes
    });
});
```

The aspect ratio is set via `aspectRatio: '225:300'` which is a string. I've created a session variable as an exact string '225:300' for the aspect ratio in php and I'm stumped on how to pass it on to aspectRatio.

I've tried setting it as a variable `var aspect_ratio = <?php echo $_SESSION['aspect_ratio']; ?>;` and then calling `aspectRatio: aspect_ratio,` but that doesn't seem to work.

I've moved the variable to different places in the script, tried calling it with and without single and double quotes, brackets, etc.

How do I get this to work?